# Row within a Row with Ext GWT Grid

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Is is possible to have a `RowExpander` that is not HTML but rather another Row? That is, a row have a expand [+] icon then when expanded, sub rows appear like a "child-row""?

For example I have a `List<ModelData>` like this:

```
ModelData column1 = new BaseModelData();
column1.set("Date", "11-11-11");
column1.set("Time", "11:11:11");
column1.set("Code", "abcdef");
column1.set("Status", "OK");

ModelData column2 = new BaseModelData();
column2.set("Date", "11-11-11");
column2.set("Time", "12:11:11");
column2.set("Code", "abcdef");
column2.set("Status", "Failed");

ModelData column3 = new BaseModelData();
column3.set("Date", "11-11-11");
column3.set("Time", "13:11:11");
column3.set("Code", "abcedf");
column3.set("Status", "Failed");

ModelData column4 = new BaseModelData();
column4.set("Date", "11-11-11");
column4.set("Time", "14:11:11");
column4.set("Code", "abcdef");
column4.set("Status", "Failed");

List<ModelData> data = ...
data.add(model1);
data.add(model2);
data.add(model3);
data.add(model4);
```

And that this will be rendered in the Grid as two columns (Grouped by the `Code` and `Status` column):

```
         Date | Time     | Code   | Status
-------------------------------------
     11-11-11 | 11:11:11 | abcedf | OK
[+]  11-11-11 | 12:11:11 | abcedf | Failed
 |--->11-11-11 | 13:11:11 | abcedf | Failed
 |--->11-11-11 | 14:11:11 | abcedf | Failed
```

Something like this.

**Update:**

I was advised that the solution would be to extends the `RowExpander` class and merge with `GridView` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at **GroupingView** and **TreeGrid** and customize one of them for you purposes. It is much safer than trying to reuse GridView's rows rendering functionality.